# C# Update label real time from database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, real-time

What is a good way to update a label on your winforms by fetching result from the database. So all users get the update real time instead for starting the winform over to get the update.

```
    public partial class labelControl : UserControl
{
    public labelControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        updateLabel();
    }

    private void updateLabel()
    {
        using (Database.sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Database.connectionString))
        {
            Database.sqlConnection.Open();
            string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Information";

            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, Database.sqlConnection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (sqlReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (sqlReader.Read())
                        {
                            label1.Text = sqlReader["Text"].toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't mean to be rude but what you are asking seems to be beyond your current capabilities. Anyways, you would have to implement a monitoring/notification scheme. You need something to monitor the DB for changes and notify subscribers (e.g. your form) of the event.

Comment: I see, but it would be really helpful for bigger projects at the future. Such as booking system.

Comment: you can use SQL server Service broker. It allows to to map table and on change of data in table it allows to raise an event.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1029976/SQL-Server-Notifications-on-Record-Change-with-Sig

Answer (score 2):

try this, add a Task run at background, and sleep thread for interval of refresh.

```
    public labelControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!this.DesignMode)
        {
            RefreshLabel();
        }
    }

    private async void RefreshLabel()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (Database.sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Database.connectionString))
                    {
                        Database.sqlConnection.Open();
                        string selectQuery = "SELECT Text FROM Information WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Information)"; // you probably want the latest value

                        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, Database.sqlConnection))
                        {
                            using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (sqlReader.HasRows)
                                {
                                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                                    {
                                        ChangeLabelText(sqlReader["Text"].ToString());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // time to sleep thread
            }
        });
    }

    private void ChangeLabelText(string value)
    {
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            label1.Invoke(new Action<string>(ChangeLabelText), value);
            return;
        }
        label1.Text = value;
    }
```

Comment: Use SqlDependency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899948/how-to-monitor-changes-on-system-tables-sql-server-database

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class labelControl : UserControl
{
    private const short interval = 5;
    private Timer timer;
    public labelControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new Timer()
        timer.Interval = interval * 1000; //time to refresh the label in seconds
        timer.Tick += updateLabel;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void updateLabel()
    {  
        try
        {
        using (Database.sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Database.connectionString))
        {
            Database.sqlConnection.Open();
            string selectQuery = "SELECT Text FROM Information WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Information)"; // you probably want the latest value

            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, Database.sqlConnection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (sqlReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (sqlReader.Read())
                        {
                            label1.Text = sqlReader["Text"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
        catch()
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

with this solution you are calling your database every 5 seconds and refreshing the text of your label with the latest value from your table in database