# How to monitor changes on system tables, SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers, synchronization, monitor

I am looking for a way to monitor changes on system tables of a SQL Server database. I tried to create triggers on `sys<..>` tables, but query returns error:

> The object 'dbo.sysObjects' does not exist or is invalid for this operation

Also I tried this library: https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency. It says that requested table does not exist.

Can I create trigger for system table? Are there other ways to catch changes on system tables in C#.

My general purpose is synchronization (or replication) of database from one server to another in "real" time. May you know alternative ways how to do it?

Comment: Is this for SQL Server? What versions do you need to support?

Comment: You want to replicate the system databases along with user databases? I'm sorry, I'm just trying to understand the end goal here

Comment: This link might help: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-track-changes-in-sql-server/

Comment: This is an xy problem. http://xyproblem.info/ Maybe you want ddl triggers?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 (or higher) is used. I need to have full copy of data base on other server. For example, I have machine A with data base and same data base on machine B (previously restored from backup file from A). I need any changes (data, schema, triggers, procuders, views) are transferred from A to B immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Availability group(AG) concept for replication purpose.